# How can I select a PDF file for upload

Tags: java, android, pdf

I have a code that can select images for upload but I wanna change it to PDF how can I dot that
when I change MediaStore.Images to MediaStore.Files it doesn't work
here is my code

```
public void sec(View view){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Snackbar.make(view,"Dosyalara Erişim İçin İzin Gerekiyor",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("İzin ver", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     permissonLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            }).show();
        }else{
            permissonLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }else{
        Intent intettoFiles=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intettoFiles);
    }
}

public void registerLauncher(){
  activityResultLauncher=registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
          if(result.getResultCode()==RESULT_OK){
              Intent intentfromresult=result.getData();
              if(intentfromresult!=null){
                  CVDATA=intentfromresult.getData();
                  binding.imageView.setImageURI(CVDATA);
                 
              }
          }
      }
  });
  permissonLauncher=registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
          if (result) {
              Intent intenttoFiles=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
              activityResultLauncher.launch(intenttoFiles);
          } else{
              Toast.makeText(Profil.this, "İzin Gerekiyor!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to set the mime type `application/pdf` See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setType(java.lang.String)

Comment: Wrong -Image- collection: MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. Better do not use a collection at all.

Comment: thank you all three